# Dynamic class definiton in one file

Tags: php

I can have only one php file.

I need to define a class only on certain occasions to generate output.

Something like this:

```
if (date("j") == "1") {
    echo "Not today";
    exit;
}

new OutputGenerator();

class OutputGenerator {
    // very large definition (~3500 lines)
}
```

Problem with this code is that PHP processes the whole file and that makes the script very slow. Without the class declaration I can process ~500 requests per second. With the definition (even if I exit before it is defined) I get only ~50, which is 90% performance drop.

Conditionally requiring external file with the declaration would solve my problem, but I need to stay within this one file.

Is there a way (other than using eval() or require an external file with the definition) to do this?

Comment: does it help if you use an `else` statement for the remainder of the file?

Comment: Can you confirm that it's the class definition and not its construction that is causing the performance slowdown?

Comment: Bigger issue is since the instantiation of the class is not assigning to anything I think everything is being done in the constructor and since no parameters are going it probably using globals for everything.

Comment: The problem is, that I get the performance drop even without initializing the class. The class is just sitting at the end of the file (it is actually a LESS > CSS parser), never called, never instantiated, only in the same file. When I require it from an external file, the performance is back to ~500 requests per second. I believe this is an internal PHP thing, that it reads all the classes into memory and makes them available afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Parse time on the php file shouldn't take that long.. I think the problem is that constructor for OutputGenerator has some expensive operation going on in it.

You can conditionally create an instance of an OutputGenerator to dodge this cost.

```
 if($iNeedAnOutputGenerator){
      $og = new OutputGenerator();
 }
```

Comment: Operations within the class are not the issue. It happens even if I never call / instantiate the class.

Comment: then conditional include is the only way... unless you want to do something crazy like have the definition in a string and conditionally evaluate it... but that is madness

Comment: I think with a class definition with 3500 loc in it you probably need to reevaluate your solution. There is savings to be had there.

Comment: I agree, but the class is not my code, I just use it. Anyway.. Thanks for trying to help, I will keep experimenting and post some closure later.

Answer (score 0):

Since your script is so extremely minimal, I buy into the idea that your performance can lower significantly. None of the things you are doing are very resource intensive, so I can see that a large class definition could show a noticable difference in that case.

The most obvious answer, *if* parsing is the issue, is to use an opcode cache. From PHP 5.5 this is built in, but for any PHP version before that you should use the [APC extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC).

Even without APC though, I think 50 requests per second for such a simple script is low, and you may well have a completely different bottleneck somewhere.